# rounding off in bash

Tags: bash, shell, rounding

I was taking [a challenge on hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/bash-tutorials---compute-the-average/problem) . 
The **aim** is:

> *read* (int) **N**; then *read* **N** integers and *print* their *avg*  to *three* decimal places.

Here's the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
#file name:rdlp.sh
read N
s=0
i=1
while (($i<=$N))
     do
           read a
           s=$((s+a))
           i=$((i+1))
     done
s=$s/$N
echo  "scale=3;$s"|bc -l
fi
```

When I run the code for some inputs:

> 3  #(value of **N**)
>   4  #(**N** = ***3*** integers)
>   4
>   3

Then the output is **3.666**, but it should be ***3.667***.

So the ***QUESTION*** is that is there anyway to get it **right** (*correct rounding off*), or does it work like that only?

(the question came off when the above code was run for [**Testcase2** of the challenge at  hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/bash-tutorials---compute-the-average/problem))

Answer (score 1):

`bc` rounds down with `scale=x`.
You can printf:

```
$ printf "%.3f\n" $(echo  "scale=1000; 11/3"|bc -l)
3.667
```

or some tricky bc by adding 0.0005:

```
$ echo  "scale=1000; v=11/3; v=v+0.0005; scale=3; v/1" | bc -l
3.667
```